# Is it possible to compress or split '.blend' files within Blender? If so, how?

Tags: blend-files

I have a large blender file.

How can I compress this file and can I split the file into multiple files to ship it?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

All you need to do is check the *Compress File* box when saving. If your file is still too big, consider using a service like [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/business/landing-t65fl?_tk=sem_b_goog&_camp=sem-b-goog-us-eng-top-exact&_kw=dropbox%7Ce&_ad=50390138022%7C1t1%7Cc&gclid=Cj0KEQjwwry8BRDjsbjMpPSDvagBEiQA5oW0nAsuZb1z4le_uuTYExy8eLR6vYhvTEKaTuAhxV5phpQaAtiS8P8HAQ) or [YouSendIt](https://www.hightail.com/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=brand&mkwid=sCA8WPI0Q%7Cpcrid%7C120227173274%7Cpkw%7Cyousendit%7Cpmt%7Ce%7Cpdv%7Cc%7C&gclid=Cj0KEQjwwry8BRDjsbjMpPSDvagBEiQA5oW0nLBeFZcXGHthgh8BLpIhRNUBaXstBGUeEXLC0WGHzG0aAnPg8P8HAQ).

[image: Blender ScreenShot]

Comment: Note that this can slow down save/load times a little, it also takes up more space in some version control systems (such as subversion) - which can do binary diff's, But for personal use its fine.

Comment: Maybe add [Pasteall](http://pasteall.org/blend/) and [BlendSwap](http://www.blendswap.com/) for some blender specific services. (Note that no registration is required for Pasteall)

Answer (score 17):

If the file is made of a bunch of scenes you can import them into separate .blend files. To append a scene from a *different* file use `File > Append`. Find the file and click on it. Once you do, you should see a bunch of folders. Select the scene folder. Click on the scene you want and open it.

You can then proceed to save off each individual scene into a separate .blend file.

One other possible reason that you have a very large file is because of cached simulations/animations. If you are trying to send a directory with a bunch of sim caches, I would recommend deleting those. You can always bake them later after they're sent.

Comment: I highly recommend this for certain things, but it's important to note that this can have a huge "some assembly required" issue if stuff goes wrong; for instance, if I were to make a bookstore, I'd probably make all my models separately in their own scenes and then append them to my scene (or link, if appropriate), but this could cause issues if you have to use too many things and don't do everything perfectly.

Comment: That's true, but If your just trying to compress it once, it may make some sense. I completly agree that over time things will get complex, but if it's a one-off thing, this may work.

Comment: Make sure you don't append, but link from other files.

Comment: Also, don't delete sim caches if you know your target machine won't be able to resim them in time, or doesn't have the resources for it (RAM).