# Split big rigid body simulation file

Tags: rigid-body-simulation, blend-files, sheepit

How to split a big '.blender' file into multiple files that are less than 500MB?

For instance, if I have a rigid body simulation that sits in a file that is about 1.5GB and consist of 4000 frames, is there a way to split it into 4 different files:

file 1: frames 1--1000

file 2: frames 1001--2000

file 3: frames 2001--3000

file 4: frames 3001--4000

The only related topics I could find are:
[Is it possible to split a .blend file?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14987/is-it-possible-to-split-a-blend-file)

[Is it possible to compress or split '.blend' files within Blender? If so, how?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2/is-it-possible-to-compress-or-split-blend-files-within-blender-if-so-how)

But I don't know how it can be done with a rigid body simulation

Comment: I guess the answer is *No*. However, you could try to `zip` the `.blend` - should make it pretty small. Also consider to split it up into several chunks using `7zip`...

Comment: The main goal is to send it to sheepit render farm and they have the 500mb constraint. Is there a way to convert the rigid body bake into a set of keyframes? Will it decrease the size when split?